Wordpress - Best way to create child themes from themes that are already customized
I’m looking for advice on creating a child theme from a theme that already has customizations applied in Wordpress (6.7.1). I need to be able to update the theme, but I can’t afford to lose the customizations.
Is there a straightforward way to do this? If possible, I’d like a method that doesn’t require much coding.
Edit: This is not a duplicate of "WordPress child theme of a child theme," which discusses the complexities of creating grandchild themes (an additional layer). Here, the focus is solely on child themes.
PS: I found WordPress guidance on how to create child themes, but it requires coding expertise, which I lack. I don't want to risk compromising the website's functionality as I don't have a test environment.


This question is similar to: Wordpress child theme of a child theme. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please see edit

the method to keep customisations is to copy them in a child theme. I think that the first step to do that is that you need to learn how to copy the website to have a test site where you can work.
